# How do you initialize SerialPort in c++ using Code::Blocks on Ubuntu14.04

Tags: c++, serial-port, codeblocks, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to initialize a serial port using the SerialPort.h library but I just can't get it working. I want to use the SerialPort functions but when I coded it this way:

```
std::string port= "/dev/ttyUSB0";
SerialPort serial(const SerialPort serial);
serial.GetBaudRate();
```

The complier tells me "error: request for member ‘GetBaudRate’ in ‘serial’, which is of non-class type ‘SerialPort(SerialPort)’".

How do I fix this? I am totally inexperience with object oriented programming.

Comment: Try passing `port` into the constructor of `SerialPort`. `SerialPort serial(port);`

Comment: @JamesMoore it just gave me additional errors.
undefined reference to `SerialPort::SerialPort(std::string const&)'

Comment: Do you have `#include <SerialPort.h>` at the top of the file?

Comment: @JamesMoore Yes i have.
I've read the SerialPort class refference from (http://libserial.sourceforge.net/doxygen/class_serial_port.html) and was wondering how the constructors work. I was trying to tinker with it but it gave me the same problem.
The constructors were:
`SerialPort (const std::string &serialPortName)`
`SerialPort (const SerialPort &otherSerialPort)`

Comment: You can use `SerialStream` instead of `SerialPort` to read/write, [this may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046649/read-and-write-on-serial-port-in-ubuntu-with-c-c-and-libserial),

Comment: @JamesMoore I tried the code but it only gives me garbage values