# Reading arduino serial in C++ using codeblocks on ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, serial-port, arduino, codeblocks

I tried using and editing the code from [Read and Write on serial port in Ubuntu with C/C++ and LibSerial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9046649/4534052) and referencing from the Ubuntu manpage http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man3/LibSerial_SerialStream.3.html.

When I use the serial monitor from the Arduino IDE it works fine. But when I wanted to read it using codeblocks with C++, all I got was some garbage values.

Here's the code:

```
#include <SerialStream.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define PORT "/dev/ttyUSB0"

using namespace std;
using namespace LibSerial;
...
SerialStreamBuf::BaudRateEnum baud_rate = SerialStreamBuf::BAUD_115200;
const SerialStreamBuf::CharSizeEnum csize = SerialStreamBuf::DEFAULT_CHAR_SIZE;
const SerialStreamBuf::ParityEnum parity = SerialStreamBuf::PARITY_NONE;
short stop_bits = 1;
const SerialStreamBuf::FlowControlEnum flow_c = SerialStreamBuf::FLOW_CONTROL_NONE;
...
SerialStream(PORT, baud_rate, csize, parity, stop_bits, flow_c);
SerialStream serial_port ;
serial_port.Open(PORT) ;
...
while( 1  ){
     char next_byte;
     serial_port.get(next_byte);
     std::cerr << next_byte;
     usleep(100);
 }
```

How do I fix this? I'm not good in object oriented programming so I'm not so sure about initializing the constructors.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining two variables for the serial stream, but using the uninitialized one.  Try replacing this:

```
SerialStream(PORT, baud_rate, csize, parity, stop_bits, flow_c);
SerialStream serial_port ;
serial_port.Open(PORT) ;
```

With

```
SerialPort serial_port ;
serial_port.Open(PORT, baud_rate, csize, parity, stop_bits, flow_c);
```

and then use the `ReadByte` function.

Comment: compiler told me "error: request for member ‘Open’ in ‘serial_port’, which is of non-class type ‘SerialPort()’" but I just initialized serial_port with the contents of SerialPort right? why is it giving me this error?

Comment: I've solved the problem, instead of    `SerialPort serial_port;`    it should be    `SerialPort serial_port("/dev/ttyUSB0")`